# SQL to find discrepancy between 2 tables with same identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying minus command but not working

- Table A column ID , column Date
- Table B column ID , column Date

Compare using column `ID` in both table, e.g. table A ID 1 Date vs Table B ID 1 Date

- if dates are the same --> skip
- if dates are different, then list the `ID` and `Date` column

Is it possible to list both tables in one view?

Comment: yes, you should JOIN those tables.

Comment: would you please show any example or any query you probably have tested for it? are you using mysql or mssql...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tb1.ID, tb1.Date, tb2.Date 
FROM table1 as tb1 
    INNER JOIN table2 as tb2 
        on tb1.ID = tb2.ID 
WHERE tb1.Date <> tb2.Date
```

only shows dates that are different. does not take into account that an id could be missing on either table

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `TRUNC()` function on the date column.  The dates may be same but since time is different MINUS is treating it as 2 different dates.